# Would like to update the firestore database of certain document based on an if statement

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update certain documents 'avail' field to true only if the toolCount method I applied is more than 1.
Each document is a different tool
I am counting their quantity based on their toolName meaning if I have 2 Screens in toolName field then ++

Img of firebase:

[image]

Code:

```
  @override
  Future countTools() async {
    try {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Tools').get().then((value) {
        var toolNamesCounted = Map();
        List toolNames = [];

        value.docs.forEach((data) {
          var doc = data.data();

          toolNames.add(doc['toolName']);
        });

        toolNames.forEach((e) {
          if (!toolNamesCounted.containsKey(e)) {
            toolNamesCounted[e] = 1;
          } else {
            toolNamesCounted[e] += 1;
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Have a look at this website, they have explained it very nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect doc ids with the same field name and best way to update multiple docs is using [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Tools').get().then((value) {
  WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

  List<dynamic> toolNamesCounted = [];
  List<dynamic> toolNames = [];

  value.docs.asMap().forEach((i, data) {
    var doc = data.data();

    toolNames.add({
      'name': doc['toolName'],
      'id': value.docs[i].reference.id,
    });
  });

  // collect ids if same toolName
  toolNames.forEach((e) {
    final match = toolNamesCounted.indexWhere((element) => element['name'] == e['name']);

    // if found collect ids
    if (match >= 0) {
      toolNamesCounted[match]['ids'].add(e['id']);
    } else {
      // if not found add first record
      toolNamesCounted.add({
        'name': e['name'],
        'ids': ['${e['id']}'],
      });
    }
  });

  toolNamesCounted.forEach((e) {
    // if collected ids array more than 2 add batches
    if (e['ids'].length >= 2) {
      e['ids'].forEach((e) {
        batch.update(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Tools').doc(e), {'avail': true});
      });
    }
  });

  // update all the docs
  batch.commit();
});
```